# tail() equivalent using dbplyr? (i.e. return last x rows of database table)

Tags: r, dplyr, dbplyr

Suppose using dbplyr, we have something like

```
library(dbplyr)

sometable %>%
  head()
```

then we see the first 6 rows.

But if we try this we see an error

```
sometable %>%
  tail()
# Error: tail() is not supported by sql sources
```

which is [expected behaviour of dbplyr](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dbplyr/vignettes/dbplyr.html):

> Because you can’t find the last few rows without executing the whole query, you can’t use tail().

Question: how do we do the `tail()` equivalent in this situation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, the order of SQL queries should never be assumed, as the DBMS may store it in an order that is ideal for indexing or other reasons, and not based on the order you want. Because of that, a common "best practice" for SQL queries is to either (a) assume the data is unordered (and perhaps that the order may change, though I've not seen this in practice); or (b) force ordering in the query.

From this, consider arranging your data in a descending manner and use `head`.

For instance, if I have a table `MyTable` with a numeric field `MyNumber`, then

```r
library(dplyr)
library(dbplyr)
tb <- tbl(con, "MyTable")
tb %>%
  arrange(MyNumber) %>%
  tail() %>%
  sql_render()
# Error: tail() is not supported by sql sources
tb %>%
  arrange(MyNumber) %>%
  head() %>%
  sql_render()
# <SQL> SELECT TOP(6) *
# FROM "MyTable"
# ORDER BY "MyNumber"
tb %>%
  arrange(desc(MyNumber)) %>%
  head() %>%
  sql_render()
# <SQL> SELECT TOP(6) *
# FROM "MyTable"
# ORDER BY "MyNumber" DESC
```

(This is (obviously) demonstrated on a SQL Server connection, but the premise should work just as well for other DBMS types, they'll just shift from `SELECT TOP(6) ...` to `SELECT ... LIMIT 6` or similar.)

Comment: This is a great explanation, but after reading it, I'm not sure what to do?

Comment: If `sometable %>% arrange(id) %>% tail()` I get the same error as before

Comment: `%>% arrange(desc(id)) %>% head()`?